# Group Policy Management on Server 2008

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2008

In an SBS 2008 (Server 2008) Domain, the Group Policy Management tool on the server is missing a bunch of settings that I know exist in RSAT for Win7.

Is there a way of updating the GPMC in Server 2008 to match that of Server 2008 R2/RSAT? Or is MS forcing me to commandeer a user's desktop in order to manage the server?

TIA

Comment: What's missing?

Comment: Point and Print overrides for Computer (it only has for User - or vise versa, but it should exist in both). Item Targeting with Win7 (it ends in Vista). All Windows Updates have been applied to the server, if there is a GP update to add these features to the server I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

Group Policy Management Console reads the ADMX (and ADML) files from your c:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions folder, and then builds the policies in the SysVol\\Policies folder to replicate to all DCs and apply to all computers.

Windows 7 includes updated ADMX. To use these ADMX on your domain you can do two things:
1) Install RSAT on a Win7 Domain Member and admin your GP from there.
2) Build a Central Store to hold your ADMX and copy in the Win7 ADMX/L.

The disadvantage of 2 is that the Group Policy Editor is a little newer in Win7 than Server 2008, but you will get all the new Win7 settings.

To build your central store follow these instructions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748955%28WS.10%29.aspx

Every .admx in the Central Store will override the local .admx.